# Wireless Network Adapter unclaimed if other netwerk is active

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 16.10, ethernet

When I boot up my computer when there is another network adaptor active (Ethernet adaptor in my USB-C dock, or even a virtual network created by Docker), my WLAN adaptor stays 'unclaimed':

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
   version: 32
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enxd481d722ec02
   serial: d4:81:d7:22:ec:02
   size: 1Gbit/s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   capacity: 1Gbit/s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.08.6 duplex=full ip=192.103.1.122 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s                                                                                                                                                                                                                       resources: memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
```

After disconnecting my Ethernet adaptor and removing docker, my wlan is working fine. When I plugin my Ethernet adaptor after connecting to WiFi, it's also working fine.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0617 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0835:2a01 Action Star Enterprise Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5742 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0091 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2742 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Full debug info is here at [Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24379220/)

Why does my wireless adaptor stays unclaimed and how can I fix this?

I'm using Kubuntu 17.04 on a Dell XPS 13 9360 (problem already existed while using 16.10).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue after updating my kernel. Per `lsmod`, the `ath10k_pci` module isn't getting loaded automatically at startup. **A workaround is to load it manually with `modprobe ath10k_pci`**, which at least gets the adapter running.

I'm not sure why the module isn't loaded automatically. It's not blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/*`, and it didn't help to add it and its dependencies to `/etc/modules`. Its modalias in /sys does correctly match one of the regexp's returned by `modinfo ath10k_pci`.